# Wrapping text within container without messing up styling in the parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with text wrapping within my container. Working code snippet below.

In the sample above, everything works fine until the stepper-hor container has enough space to present the content:
[image]

I'd like the step-text container (box with blue border) to always stay to in line with step-additional-label container (box with green border). Step-text container (box with blue border) should also wrap the text inside when container's width shrinks.

Currently, when I set stepper-hor width to 350px, step-text container (box with blue border) goes below the box with green border:
[image]

**What I wish to achieve is something like this:**
[image]

I've tried using different variations of
display: inline-block;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
in lines 64-65 but that didn't work as expected and often messed up the horizontal alignment between the step-circle-active and step-text.
Any help is very much appreciated.
Here is a more editing-friendly sandbox to play around:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-breeze-qm4bf?file=/styles.css

EDIT: @Temani and @Daniel below suggested display: flex; which helped nicely.
Here is the codesandbox fork with implemented changes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-wescoff-wgyny?file=/styles.css

Thank you lads.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial Light";
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.stepper-hor {
  background-color: #252525;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* width: 350px; */
  /* HERE YOU CAN CHANGE THE WIDTH OF THE CONTAINER */
}

.step-container {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.459);
  min-height: 63px;
  margin: 0;
}

.step-circle-default {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.step-circle-active {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  background-color: #d85603;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.step-additional-label {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.575);
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 26px;
  font-size: 0.59rem;
  color: #666666;
  padding-right: 21px;
}

.step-text {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.404);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 0.82rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 54px;
  top: 4px;
}

.step-line {
  border: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-hor">
  <p class="step-container" }>
    <span class="step-circle-default">1</span>
    <span class="step-additional-label">100%</span>
    <span class="step-text">Take a shower</span>
  </p>
  <p class="step-container" }>
    <span class="step-circle-default">2</span>
    <span class="step-additional-label">10%</span>
    <span class="step-text">Read a book</span>
  </p>
  <p class="step-container" }>
    <span class="step-circle-active">13</span>
    <span class="step-additional-label">79%</span>
    <span class="step-text">
            Do some activity with long description that will require more space
          </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: display:flex to `.step-container`

Comment: Perfection, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `step-container` structure and use `display: flex` in order to achieve the result you want.

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div class="step-container">
    <div class="stats">
        <span class="step-circle-active">13</span>
        <span class="step-additional-label">79%</span>
    </div>
    <p class="step-text">
        Do some activity with long description that will require more space
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.step-container {
    display: flex;
}

.step-container .stats {
    display: flex;
}
```

There is no point in creating the `step-container` as a `p` element with multiple spans in it.

Comment: Thanks mate. Temani already proposed solution with display: flex and it worked greatly after tweaking rest of the css code a bit. I will also consider your suggestion regarding restructuring the step-container but I still need to add additional thing (a line between each step) which might impact the structure as well.

Answer (score -1):

Adding CSS property `display: flex;` to the container **.step-container** will do the thing. [image: Working Code]